# Looking for California sales tax data by zip

Tags: data-request, data.gov, taxes

I'm building a store and I need to calculate the sales tax at checkout only for clients that reside in California. I looked for an API, but all of them charge a monthly fee. Seeing as I only need this for one state, I would be better off with a simple mapping based on zip codes. Any ideas?

Comment: Closest I can offer is Tax rate by City & County - https://www.cdtfa.ca.gov/taxes-and-fees/sales-use-tax-rates.htm Look for the download header, check out the latest Excel sheet (you can import it in Google sheets) - it will need you to clean up the headers. You could try finding a Zipcode -> City sheet and use that as a helper.

Answer (score 1):

Avalara (at this time) offers a free download by state which includes zip codes and a breakdown of the tax amounts.

https://www.avalara.com/taxrates/en/download-tax-tables.html